# let an URL link become clickable after using by formula

Tags: excel, google-sheets

**Scenario**

*column A*

1. [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
2. a
3. b
4. c

The url link should be clickable for now, however it's become unclickable after I'm using some formula to combine it. here is the formula I'm using

=CONCATENATE(HYPERLINK(A1,A1),char(10),A2,A3,A4)

*output*

"www.google.com

abc"

Is there any way to let my URL become clickable after combining some formula?

Comment: Move the CONCATENATE *inside* the HYPERLINK?

Comment: all in one cell?

Comment: My purpose is to output in 1 cell
"www,google.com
abc"

however, I'm just only want to let "www,google.com" become clickable link and the rest just remain as normal wording in the cell.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The HYPERLINK should be outside, since the last thing you need is the link

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(A1,char(10),A2,A3,A4), "title")
```

[Excel snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1Lsj.png)

Comment: My purpose is to output in 1 cell
"www,google.com
abc"

however, I'm just only want to let "www,google.com" become clickable link and the rest just remain as normal wording in the cell.

Comment: it's not possible because the hyperlink is in the CELL, not in the text like is in a Word document.
Make it two columns if you want only the first part clicable.